# Comparing checklistbox items to array

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms, for-loop, checklistbox

So, i have a checklistbox that contains string values like:

- asdf-432-qwer-vcxz
- rewq-123-qwer-vcxz
- rety-323-qw65-vcyt
- kjhf-232-ouyy-bjkl
- ...

And i have an array(onlineVaults) that contains some of the same values that in checklistbox like:

- rety-323-qw65-vcyt
- asdf-432-qwer-vcxz

Now i want to check only those values in checklistbox that are in the array. Others should be unchecked.

```
for (int i = 0; i < checklistbox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if (onlineVaults.Contains(checklistbox.Items[i]))
    {
        checklistbox.SetItemChecked(i, true);
    }
}
```

I have tried it to figure out like this, but it doesn't work. It only checks one value and nothing else. What i should do?

Comment: Can you provide a concrete example (have you tried this with the very values given in the question)? Which item remains checked in the end?

Comment: What is the default state of each checkbox? have you tried adding the `else` block to your if statement that sets the boxes to unchecked?

Comment: Default state of each checkbox is unchecked. i tried to add `else` statement but it didn't work out @ReeceKenney

Comment: Please note that in WinForms, the control is called [`CheckedListBox`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Your code (with the exact values shown in your question) works for me; two of the four values are checked. If it does not work for you, there must be something else going on that we cannot see in the code snippets you are showing here.

Comment: I did some testing and found out that it always checks only the last value in `onlineVaults` @O.R.Mapper

Comment: @niklang: Well, it doesn't when I try. Are there any event handlers bound to your control, or any non-standard settings?

Comment: Provide more code please. Where does this `onlineVaults` came from? Are you absolutely sure that there are values and not nulls there ? Are there multi-threading involved ?

Comment: Values are okay, i print those on file before i compare them. And they are same kind. @Fabjan

Comment: The default value for `SelectionMode` property is `One`. Have you set it to either `MultiSimple` or `MultiExtended`?

Comment: @Rubidium37: The [`SelectionMode` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.selectionmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) merely controls how many items can be *highlighted*. At any time, an unlimited number of items can still be *checked*. Note that the docs even say: "For CheckedListBox objects, multiple selection is not supported. You can set the mode to one item or no items."

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var checklistbox = new List<string>
{
     "asdf-432-qwer-vcxz",
     "rewq-123-qwer-vcxz",
     "rety-323-qw65-vcyt",
     "kjhf-232-ouyy-bjkl"
};
var onlineVaults = new List<string>
{
     "rety-323-qw65-vcyt",
     "asdf-432-qwer-vcxz"
};

for (int i = 0; i < checklistbox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    checklistbox.SetItemChecked(i, onlineVaults.Contains(checklistbox.Items[i]));            
}
```

EDIT:

To ignore case and trim values, try this

```
for (int i = 0; i < checklistbox.Items.Count; i++)
{
    checklistbox.SetItemChecked(i, IsValueExist(onlineVaults, checklistbox.Items[i]));            
}

private bool IsValueExist(List<string> list, string value)
{
    return list.Any(x => string.Compare(x.Trim(), value.Trim(), StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);        
}
```

Comment: Didn't work, does the same thing that my `if else` code.

Comment: @M.NasserJavaid: Isn't it [this method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.setitemchecked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: @niklang Can you see values using debug, is there need to trim values?

Comment: Yes they are ok, values are like this: {D1E8AD81-XXX-4D9C-VFDC-3B7AD146T5DE} @M.NasserJavaid

Comment: I mean to say, if there are some alphabets case difference or if any item has white space in left or right side then there will be matching issue.